# How to convert Python dict to a specifically-typed object?

Tags: python, dictionary, metaprogramming

Using Python 2.7 I need to convert a dictionary to a typed object.

For example if I have this dict :

```
mapy = {'id': 1, 'name': 'bob'}
```

I need some way to generate this class at runtime given the previous map and the type name (which is `'Person'` in this example):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

Should I consider using meta-programming techniques and if so which one exactly (decorators, metaclasses, ...)?

Please note that I don't just need to convert a dict to an object; I also need to attach some type information to the resulting object.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to generate an `__init__` method based on the given `dict`:

```
def make_init(d):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name in d:
            setattr(self, name, kwargs[name])
    return __init__
```

Then, use the 3-argument form of `type` to create a class at run-time.

```
type_name = "Person"
Person = type(type_name, (object,), { '__init__': make_init(mapy) })
```

Finally, instantiate the class using the dictionary to provide arguments to `__init__`:

```
obj = Person(**mapy)
```

Comment: You can replace that `for` loop with `self.__dict__.update(d)`, and there's a more explicit way to create a class on the fly (see my example below).

Answer (score 6):

You could try `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

mapy = { 'id' : 1, 'name' : 'bob'}

# Note that the order of `mapy.keys()` is unpredictable.
Person = namedtuple('Person', mapy.keys())

p = Person(**mapy)
p.id
p.name
```

Comment: This is a good approach. The only issue I see is that it creates a read-only object (since its a subclass of `tuple`).

Comment: @Dan: good point. If OP requires a read/write object, they can look at the implementation of `namedtuple` to see how to generate an appropriate class definition on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2):

Your request has a problem: "I don't just need to convert a dict to an object; I also need to attach **some type information** to the resulting object." The problem is that "some type information" is too vague. The most literal implementation will create a new class for every object, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Try this:

```
def make_dict_into_object(name, d):
    class Dummy(object):
        def __init__(self, attr):
            self.__dict__.update(attr)
    Dummy.__name__ = name

    return Dummy(d)   

mapy = { 'id' : 1, 'name' : 'bob'}
bob = make_dict_into_object('Person', mapy)
print bob.name

mapx = { 'id' : 1, 'name' : 'steve'}
steve = make_dict_into_object('Person', mapx)
print steve.id
```

So far so good, right? But this is probably **not** want you want. After running the above, add this:

```
print type(steve) == type(bob)
```

The result will be **False**, because `make_dict_into_class` generates a new class on every call. Attaching "some type information" to the object is just silly because it's a new type for every object.

There are a variety of ways to fix this, depending on your actual use case for the resultant objects. One way would be to cache the newly-created classes, and assume that subsequent calls with the same name refer to the same class:

```
class_cache = {}
def make_dict_into_object(name, d):
    the_class = class_cache.setdefault(name, None)
    if the_class is None:
        class the_class(object):
            def __init__(self, attr):
                self.__dict__.update(attr)
        the_class.__name__ = name
        class_cache[name]=the_class

    return the_class(d)
```

Using this version, `bob` and `steve` end up with the same type:

```
mapy = { 'id' : 1, 'name' : 'bob'}
bob = make_dict_into_class('Person', mapy)
print bob.name

mapx = { 'id' : 1, 'name' : 'steve'}
steve = make_dict_into_class('Person', mapx)
print steve.id

print type(steve) == type(bob)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your `__init__` would have actual arguments to supply the attribute values:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

Then you can unpack the dictionary straight into it:

```
>>> p = Person(**{'id': 1, 'name': 'bob'})
>>> p.id
1
>>> p.name
'bob'
>>> p
<__main__.Person object at 0x02DA5730>
```

Comment: The class definition needs to be generated programatically i.e the definition is not present when the program is launched

Comment: @Chedy2149 then nneonneo's `namedtuple` suggestion is probably your best bet, but I'd be interested to hear why exactly you think this is necessary - do your "classes" not have instance methods?

Comment: @Chedy2149, classes in Python are first-class objects. It is very easy to create a new class on-the-fly and give it the name and attributes that you want; see my answer below.